# Can we use session in API to store the user details in Android Studio?

Tags: php, android, session

I am developing an Android Application. in this, i want to use session in (API)PHP file.

In PHP, we are using session like
if i am using session then no data is fetched if i put it as an comment then the data is fetching properly.

```
<?php
    include ("connection.php");
    $response = array();
    session_start();

    if (isset($_REQUEST['username']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && isset($_REQUEST['Spinner']) ){
    $remail = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $rpass = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $rspinner =$_REQUEST['Spinner'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM portal_login WHERE pl_email='$remail' AND pl_password='$rpass' AND pl_department='$rspinner'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $ID   = $row["pl_id"];
            $User = $row["pl_username"];
            $Dept = $row["pl_department"];
            $Uemail = $row["pl_email"];

            $response["success"]=1;
            $response["userid"]=$row['pl_id'];
            $response["username"]=$row['pl_username'];
            $response["department"]=$row['pl_department'];
            $response["email"]=$row['pl_email'];


            $_SESSION['e_username']=$User;
            $_SESSION['e_department']=$Dept;
            $_SESSION['e_id']=$ID;


        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No user found.";
    }
    }
    else 
    {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

but this api is not working in android.. is there any other way to use session in API?

Comment: You should really not be building API's that still rely on the mysql_ functions that no longer exist in PHP after a [deprecation of about 3 years](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php#migration55.deprecated.mysql). On top of that, your code is wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Oldskool do we have any other method?

Comment: Yes, click the first link to the PHP documentation, it'll show you 2 alternatives that are still supported.

Comment: @Oldskool if i want to use this same code in same way is there any possibilties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST API is for stateless, so you cannot store anything on the server.

That means Session will not works.

Comment: So how can i store the data in session
i want to store usename,email and user_id in my application
please suggest me for this..

Comment: Can i get a data from Java file to PHP API ?

Comment: You can used AccessToken for this.

Comment: Please go through the below link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a session on your server via your API you can implement basic OAuth2 authentication, at its most simple level, this comprises of:

1. User authenticates via the API with a username and password.
2. API returns a GUID for that session, this becomes the user's authentication token. Store these in a Sessions table in your database. Timestamp each session entry so you can apply a custom timeout if you wish (heavily recommended).
3. For every API call that requires the user to be authenticated, check for a custom session ID in the header of that request (give it a name like X-SessionId).
4. If the above ID is not present in the header of these calls, return unauthorised. If it is, execute the method and return the appropriate response to that user.

Also, as mentioned by others in the above comments, do not use deprecated MySQL methods and make sure you use prepared statements to block against SQL injection.

[EDIT]

Forgot to mention, using the $_REQUEST object allows for authentication over GET. This is really bad. Use $_POST instead. You should never allow for authentication to be sent over GET.

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of search i found that it is useless to use session, 
i found that the best solution is to send every thing you want with the HTTP request either with header or with data section with  request .